# Collision-Resistance Hash Function PRF

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, pseudo-random-function

I am trying to solve the following question with an example/proof. The question is from *Introduction to Modern Cryptography* by Katz and Lindell. Any help would be appreciated.

> [image]

Answer (score 3):

Hints:

For (a), suppose you had a collision with $\hat{H}$; how could you use that to demonstrate a collision with $H$?  What does that imply?

For (b), could you construct a collision with $\hat{H}$, that is, find two different messages $x_1||x_2$ and $x'_1||x'_2$ with $\hat{H}(x_1||x_2) = \hat{H}(x'_1||x'_2)$?